# How can I execute a non named file on terminal with Neovim?

Tags: neovim, terminal, terminal-buffer

Some time ago, I've made [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/31744/32434) where I asked how to execute a file on the terminal with Neovim... The solution I found was the following `:terminal bash %` . Knowing that, I made the following configuration on my `init.vim` file:

```
function! ExecuteOnTerminal(type) range
    if (&ft=='javascript')
        if a:type == "V"
            :vert botright '<,'> terminal node %
        else
            :vert botright terminal node %
        endif
    elseif (&ft=='sh')
        if a:type == "V"
            :vert botright '<,'> terminal bash %
        else
            :vert botright terminal bash %
        endif
    elseif (&ft=='python')
        if a:type == "V"
            :vert botright '<,'> terminal python3 %
        else
            :vert botright terminal python3 %
        endif
    endif
endfunction

vnoremap <silent> <F6> :call ExecuteOnTerminal("V")<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <F6> :call ExecuteOnTerminal("I")<CR>
```

The above configuration works perfectly fine, it allows me to execute a file with `bash`, `node.js` and `python` when I press `F6`... And if I select some lines and press `F6` it`ll execute only the selected lines.

The problem is that in my context, I need to execute files that are not stored on the disk. Let's say I have the following `file.sh`:

```
echo "Hello World"
```

I need to open this file with `cat file.sh | nvim -` (not `nvim file.sh`)... When I do that, if I try using the command `:vert botright terminal bash %` I receive the error:

`E499: Empty file name for '%' or '#', only works with ":p:h"`

I tried using `set ft=sh` but it didn't work as well. Is there any workaround for this problem? In a way that I don't need to save this file on the disk to execute it with `nvim`?

---

Observation: With `vim`, I have a similar configuration in my `vimrc` file, the only difference is that I use the commands `:vert botright '<,'> %terminal bash` and `vert botright %terminal bash` instead. With `vim` it works perfectly fine to execute files opened from pipe. Like in `cat file.sh | vi -`. This issue only exists on NeoVim.

Comment: Depending on what you’re running, you can use `term_start` and a command with the text to execute or an `in_buf` if the command accepts stdin

Comment: You might want to check out the [vim-slime](https://github.com/jpalardy/vim-slime) plug-in.

Comment: ...or indeed the `:make` command.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this problem by creating the following vimscript:

```
function! ExecuteOnTerminal(type) range
    if (&ft=='javascript')
        if a:type == "V"
            '<,'>w! /tmp/file.js
        else
            :w! /tmp/file.js
        endif
        :vert sp | terminal node /tmp/file.js  
        call system('xdotool key "Control_L+w" ; xdotool type r')
    elseif (&ft=='bash' || &ft=='sh')
        if a:type == "V"
            '<,'>w! /tmp/file.bash
        else
            :w! /tmp/file.bash
        endif
        :vert sp | terminal bash /tmp/file.bash
        call system('xdotool key "Control_L+w" ; xdotool type r')
    elseif (&ft=='python')
        if a:type == "V"
            '<,'>w! /tmp/file.py
        else
            :w! /tmp/file.py
        endif
        :vert sp | terminal python3 /tmp/file.py
        call system('xdotool key "Control_L+w" ; xdotool type r')
    endif
endfunction

vnoremap <silent> <F6> :call ExecuteOnTerminal("V")<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <F6> :call ExecuteOnTerminal("I")<CR>
```

In this solution, a temporary file with the content of the file was created.

I wanted to make NeoVim behavior exactly the same as Vim, so I've also used `xdotool` from the system to press `Ctrl+w` and `r` to switch sides of the terminal window. The logic here is writing a temporary file with its extension in `/tmp` and then executing it with `terminal language /tmp/file.extension`. The result on NeoVim after pressing `F6` is:

[image]